# Parallel processing with Google Earth Engine and Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, parallel-processing, google-kubernetes-engine, google-earth-engine, google-cloud-scheduler

I am trying to figure out an optimal way to parallelize the following:

1. Generate an image from Google Earth Engine and have it exported into a Google Cloud Storage bucket.
2. Push this image from the Cloud Storage bucket to a virtual machine running on Google Cloud Platform (most likely using Google Compute Engine).
3. Run a script that processes this image in the virtual machine. This will generate a new product.
4. Push the new product back to Google Earth Engine as an Earth Engine Asset.

These steps would probably be done hundreds of times so parallelization would be necessary. We would have multiple VMs available on Google Cloud that would act as the nodes to process the incoming data. I need a way to automate/schedule these tasks. The automater would be able to push the image generated from Earth Engine to an available VM (or node) and know when it needs to wait before a node is available to use before pushing an image. Could Kubernetes solve this problem? I don't know much about Kubernetes, but I am all for any available options.

Answer (score 1):

By using **Cloud Scheduler** for scheduling and **Pub/Sub** for distributed messaging, you can reliably schedule tasks across a fleet of Compute Engine instances.

If you need to schedule and orchestrate complex workflows across other products or clouds, consider using [Cloud Composer](https://cloud.google.com/composer) instead.

This [document](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/reliable-task-scheduling-compute-engine) has a detailed explanation on using cloud scheduler.

Comment: Thanks so much! I will look into this.